# ArcGIS Server and F5

Tags: arcgis-server, f5

Have any one luck with F5 and ArcGIS server 9.3.1. How can F5 understand that a service in ArcGIS server is not available (There will be always a response if service is not available).

Answer (score 0):

F5 Never knows about the services as it actually deals with SOM not with SOC, it needs a spatial confguration in F5 to do so. I am not sure how in F5 you can do but I know you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, F5 can send frequent probe requests to the service URL, and the response will indicate if the service is up (returning 200) or is down/not available (returning 404) .

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a [custom health monitor](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-monitors-reference-11-6-0/1.html) to the pool. If this is a web server, you will want to use an [HTTP or HTTPS health monitor](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/2000/100/sol2167.html), but there are also TCP, UDP, SIP, scripts and many other kinds of health monitors.